# Load div content with result of post data with jquery and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have just started with Jquery and am trying to understand it.
Therefore I do apologize if my question seems stupid :)

On click of a text, I want in this case "Home" I want the  to show the result of the posted data in html.

This is what I have put down:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="core/jscripts/jquery/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="home">HOME</p>
<div id="pagesdiv">

</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#home").click(function(){
            $.post("core/scripts/loadpages.php",
                {
                    page:"home"
                },
                function(data){
                    ("#pagesdiv").html(data);
                });
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have checked the loadpages.php file and when I post "page: home" it returns the correct result. What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance for all of your help!

Comment: Could you show us the code of `loadpages.php` ?

Comment: if you mean `$("#pagesdiv").html(data);` so you forgot `$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#home").click(function(){
            $.post("core/scripts/loadpages.php",
                {
                    page:"home"
                },
                function(data){
                    $("#pagesdiv").html(data);
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I cant believe it was only the $ missing LOL!

Comment: @ ManouHH did `data` gives value what u want?. Usually it will be in this format `[object object],[object object]`

Comment: It did give me the value I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the $ -sign before ("#pagesdiv") in your response function.

Answer (score 0):

U need to convert data like this. then use value.URVALUENAME to get value.

```
function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
       $("#pagesdiv").html(value.URVALUENAME);
    });
```